# listview box not displaying data in details view

Tags: c#, winforms

I googled this question in many forms but couldn't find an answer applicable to me also..

I have a list view box in windows forms application and in that I add some items in runtime like the code I shown below:

```
lvinfo.Items.Add("Script executed successfully in " + dbname + " database");
```

The same code I am using several times for updates of execution and this works fine when I give the view as list or something else...

And also I am not clearing these items at any point of time in my code..When I googled I could find the answers related to clearing items..

My problem is when I set view property as Details, the text/content in the list view box is not displayed..or it is hidden..

EDIT:
[image: How can I set the width of this column based on the content of the column?]

I tried

```
columnHeader1.AutoResize(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.ColumnContent);
```

Any response would be really appreciated..

Comment: Are you looking for `lvinfo.Items.Clear();`? Its really hard to understand what you asking.

Comment: @Reniuz:nope...cee my edited question

Comment: I don't understand what your asking for.. first up are you using Windows Forms? and is you're problem that you can't clear items from the list or that items are being cleared from the list in error?

Comment: @Dead.Rabit:cee my edited question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it is because you haven't add any columns to your list view. In details view you should add at least one column to display your item.Try this before adding your items:

```
listView1.Columns.Add("myColumnHeader");
```

Comment: Tried your code..but doesnt works for me..Seems something is writing over there in my list box..but its not visible..i think..While clicking on a button I can see the vertical scrollbar appears, that means something is being written over there in the listitem box.but not visible..

Comment: Now it is working.But how can I change the width of the column I added now?Is it possible to change the width at the runtime based on the length of the item it recieves?

Comment: @vysakh Yes you should call the columnHeader1.AutoResize method as you did, but the trick is you should call that after adding all of your items.

Answer (score 0):

Have you created column headers for your ListView as the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.view.aspx) states:

> If your ListView control does not have any column headers specified
>   and you set the View property to View.Details, the ListView control
>   will not display any items. If your ListView control does not have any
>   column headers specified and you set the View property to View.Tile,
>   the ListView control will not display any subitems.

and

> Although columns are only displayed in the details view, subitems
>   without column headers will not display in either the details view or
>   the tile view.

Theres also an example further down the page for setting up column headers

Comment: Tried your code..but doesnt works for me..Seems something is writing over there in my list box..but its not visible..i think..While clicking on a button I can see the vertical scrollbar appears, that means something is being written over there in the listitem box.but not visible..

Comment: You need to add columns to be able to use the `View=Details`, and to have something to display in those columns you need to setup sub items to display in columns.. so presuming you've added a single column your listed code should change to `lvinfo.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new[] {"Script executed successfully in " + dbname + " database"});`. If you've done all that correctly and it's still not working then switching to `Details` isn't the problem (though you say it triggers the issue). In that case you should give a more detailed code listing because I don't have enough information to help.